# Loop Audio File in Alexa

Tags: javascript, audio, alexa-skills-kit

What's the simplest way to make my Alexa skill loop this function? The below code features a static URL, but in the end this will be updated each time the function is looped.

```
'RandomVerse': function () {


   connection.query('SELECT versetext, book, reference  FROM myverses ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1', 
    function (error, results, fields) {
    console.log(error);
    console.log(results[0].versetext);
    const AUDIO ='<audio src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/..." />'
    this.emit(':tell', AUDIO);

     }.bind(this));


    },
```